# Angularjs ng-click is not working in IE 11, but working fine with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angularjs

Here is my HTML code.

```
<button id="test" ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Test">Test</button>
```

Function inside controller.

```
$scope.test = function(){
    alert("hi");
}
```

Note: I have added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to my `index.html` page.

Comment: Based on what you have posted, it should work unless you havent included the function in the correct controller as expected by the HTML